# Block Notifications From an App (Private API)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

Hi I am building an internal distribution app and from within the app I would like it to hide incoming notifications, even if the iPhone is asleep.  Basically my app will be active and if the screen sleeps I would like to hide incoming notifications from being displayed.  I don't want to block them entirely, just hide them while my app is active.  Are there any private API's someone can point me to to being able to accomplish this?  Or does my app not have any control over them when the iPhone is asleep? Even with private API's.  Thank you!